# Default value no funciona correctamente en react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Tengo cierto bug, ya que no puedo pasar el defaultValue usando react-select, estos no aparecen en este input, ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde

- Geométrico

Es lo que deberia estar adentro del input

mi codigo es:

```
<ReactSelect isMulti name="motivos" defaultValue={props.motivos} id="motivos" options={motivosList} className="basic-multi-select" onChange={(e) => { props.changeMotivos(e)}} />
<ul>
   {props.motivos.map(ele => (
       <li>{ele.label}</li>
   ))}
</ul>
```

motivosList es:

```
axios.get('/motivos').then(resp => {
  const dtemp = []
  resp.data.forEach(element => {
     dtemp.push({ value: element.id, label: element.nombre })
  });
  setMotivosList(dtemp)
})
```

en cuanto a motivos solo es un array que contiene:

```
{
   value: 1,
   label: "Nombre"
}
```

y changeMotivos(e) es una funcion que usa un setMotivos() para cambiarlo

precisamente no se que es lo que puede estar saliendo mal o que detalle estoy ignorando ya que use este mismo procedimiento en otro componente y si me funciono bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar **react-select** de manera controlada o no.

Dado que estás usando una función **onChange**, lo lógico es que el componentene use la prop **value**, y no **defaultValue**.

Los tags `<ul>` no deberían ser necesarios, ya que la prop **options** se encarga de eso.

```
const motivos = [{
    value: 1,
    label: 'Nombre'
}];

const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

<Select
    isMulti
    options={motivos}
    value={selected}
    onChange={setSelected}
/>
```